# What is the process of finding the remainder in division called?

Tags: mathematics, programming, computing

Is there any one word for the process of calculating the remainder (division)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll post an answer there as soon as I the timer ends. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: It's not listed as a ***verb*** in the full OED but ***mod = modulo** (preposition)* is used that way in many written instances of [*{perform some calculation} and **mod** the result*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and+mod+the+result%22)

Comment: @FF 'mod' is a binary operation and a noncommutative one at that. You can't mod a single number any more than you can subtract say 23 in a vacuum. Even '_Mod_ a and b' doesn't make any more sense than '_Subtract_ 28 and 23'. // '28 minus 23' and '28 mod 23' (both of which have the product 5) are fine. ('Product' is the general term for the output of a function hereabouts, not just the term when the binary operation is 'multiply'.)

Comment: Please note that your title is a single-word request, and should be tagged as such, and an example sentence with a suitable space given. The answer given is '[perform] the modulo operation', which is of course not the single word you request.

Comment: [The computation of the quotient and the remainder from the dividend and the divisor is called division or — in case of ambiguity — Euclidean division. The theorem is frequently referred to as the division algorithm (although it is a theorem and not an algorithm), because its proof as given below lends itself to a simple division algorithm for computing q and r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modular arithmetic (and in computer science – see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) it's called the *Modulo operation* and is abbreviated mod, placed as normal between the elements of the binary operation e.g.

5 mod 2 = 1.

Comment: Indeed @herrison, I wrote the words myself, then added link to Wikipedia for extra info. I was perplexed and upset to see this comment asking to attribute the link. Surely the link shows the source. I was trying to formulate a reply, and you kindly did it for me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, OK, I see what you're saying now, I didn't get it at first as I wrote "5 mod 2 = 1" from my own head as the simplest non-trivial example I could think of. Now I've read the Wikipedia article fully and see it uses that example too, but that's like saying, "here is an example of addition: 2+2=4" COPYRIGHT! I think that's taking copyright too far. But please feel free edit my answer to attribute copyright, I don't know how to do that.